# Angular 2 - how to get value from select / option

Tags: javascript, angular

The majority of select / option solutions for Angular 2 work in a way that we return the actual content, not the `value` attribute. However, since I'm still learning Angular 2, I want to get the actual `value` attribute on clicking a button. I managed to somewhat solve this issue, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. 
Below is the example of how I'd like it to work:

```
<select #selectedCategory>
    <option *ngFor="#category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>

<button (click)="getValueFromSelect(selectedCategory.value)">

/* This returns the selected category.name, not the value attribute. */
```

The solution above creates the following HTML (note the lack of `value` attribute on `option`):

```
<select _ngcontent-oom-3="">
  <!--template bindings={}-->
  <option _ngcontent-oom-3="">stuff 1</option>
  <option _ngcontent-oom-3="">stuff 2</option>
  <option _ngcontent-oom-3="">stuff 3</option>
</select>
```

The solution below actually works, however, I need an `ngModel` in order to make it work.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory">
    <option *ngFor="#category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>
<button (click)="getValueFromSelect(selectedCategory.value)">
/* This returns the value attribute correctly; however, do I really need a ngModel for one value? */
```

What is the correct way to approach this situation?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Your "how I'd like it to work" example does work: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NZc3RWgERx2t2m1HWmCb?p=preview).  It returns the the `category.id` that is assigned to the selected option's `value` property.  I like this approach, since it does not add a property to your component.

Comment: well that's really odd, in my example when I inspect the select/option element, I don't have the `value` attribute. I basically copy/pasted your example - in your plunker, if you inspect the element, each option has a `value` attribute whereas mine doesn't. I'll update my original question with the HTML that is generated.

Comment: What version of Angular beta are you using?  And do you have any other libraries loaded?

Comment: I have this in my `package.json`: `"_id": "angular2@2.0.0-beta.14",`

Comment: The behavior is apparently different with beta.14.  See [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) -- there is something there about the select list.

Comment: well, well, well, I changed to the version you provided in the example `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/angular2.dev.js"></script>` and it works now. That's really odd. Well, it's still beta, so...

Comment: @uglycode could you please post your working code for now with angular2 beta 15 ?

Comment: No need to, the 'how I'd like it to work' part works with beta 15. No changes needed. Mark Rajcok could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the "how I'd like it to work" example does work:

```
<select #selectedCategory>
   <option *ngFor="#category of categories" [value]="category.id">
     {{category.name}}
   </option>
</select>

<button (click)="getValueFromSelect(selectedCategory.value)">click me</button>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NZc3RWgERx2t2m1HWmCb?p=preview)

However, we must use beta.15 for this to work.  See the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for beta.15 for more info:

- select: set value individually from ngModel ([e1e44a9](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/e1e44a9)), closes [#7975](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7975) [#7978](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7978)

---

I prefer this approach since it does not add a property to the component, nor do we need to use a `<form>` tag (like in @Thierry's answer).

Comment: what if there are multiple option tags within a select tag?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a control defined inline with the `ngControl` directive:

```
<form>
  <select #categoriesCtrl="ngForm" ngControl="categoriesCtrl">
    <option *ngFor="#category of categories" [value]="category.id">
      {{category.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <button (click)="getValueFromSelect(categoriesCtrl.value)">
</form>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/uWUS9RaGJ34PiXTJ1kPd?p=preview.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly does `ngControl` do, since it is very poorly documented (https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/NgControl-class.html)?

Comment: Yes, agreed ;-) Controls are to get access to values of form elements, be notified when they updates, apply validation (sync or async). There are two ways to define them: inline with `ngControl` or programmatically with `ngFormControl` / `FormBuilder`. See this article for more details: http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/.

Comment: I used the inline one since in your case you only need to get the value so there is no impact in your component class...

Comment: Note that this solution requires a `<form>` element.

Answer (score 0):

you could do using `change` event call

```
<form>
      <select #categoriesCtrl (change)='SelectedValue = categoriesCtrl.value'>
        <option *ngFor="#category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
      </select>
      <button (click)="getValueFromSelect()">Get value</button>
    </form>
```

Working Example https://plnkr.co/edit/dQZgSyw6uc67UNhNDlZv?p=preview